# What is preventing file persistence when using a Docker volume?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a Docker image named pfa-image (contains a fairly basic Express-based website), a running mongoDB container named pfa-mongo, and a docker volume named image-volume. When I run the following sequence of commands..:

```
host$ docker run -d --name pfa-container -v image-volume:/images \
  --link pfa-mongo:mongodb -p 5000:5000 pfa-image
host$ docker exec -it pfa-container /bin/bash

container:/pfa-site# cd images
container:/pfa-site/images# touch test.txt
container:/pfa-site/images# exit

host$ docker rm -f pfa-container
host$ docker run -d --name pfa-container -v image-volume:/images \
  --link pfa-mongo:mongodb -p 5000:5000 pfa-image
host$ docker exec -it pfa-container /bin/bash

container:/pfa-site# cd images
container:/pfa-site/images# ls
```

...test.txt is missing. What am I overlooking here? I am quite new to docker and somewhat new to Linux.

Thank you!

I have tried using bind mounts and volumes, to the same result.

Comment: You're mounting the volume on `/images` (`-v image-volume:/images`), but you're creating your files in `/pfa-site/images`. Trying creating them in the volume mountpoint instead.

Comment: Sheesh, thank you, I was hoping it would be something silly like that.